# Gradient $L^\infty$-estimate for heat equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, heat-equation, semigroups-of-operators, numerical-analysis-of-pde

$\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded smooth domain. Consider the homogeneous heat equation with zero boundary condition in $\Omega$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u-\Delta u=0 \quad(x,t)\in \Omega\times (0,T]\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x)\\
u(x,t)=0 \quad (x,t)\in \partial\Omega\times (0,T]
\end{cases}
Whether there is estimation like:
$$
\|\nabla u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C\|\nabla u_0\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)},
$$
here $C$ is a constant independent of $u$ and $t$.

In fact, I wish the following estimate holds: If $u_0\in C(\bar\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$, and satisfies that there exists $d_0>0$ and $C_0>0$ such that if $x\in \Omega$ with ${\rm dist}(x,\partial\Omega)\leq d_0$ then
$$
|u_0(x)|\leq C_0{\rm dist}(x,\partial\Omega)
$$
Then the solution $u(\cdot, t)$ of the heat equation will still satisfy that if $x\in \Omega$ with ${\rm dist}(x,\partial\Omega)\leq \kappa d_0$ then
$$
|u(t,x)|\leq \lambda C_0{\rm dist}(x,\partial\Omega)
$$
where $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are constants only dependent on $\Omega$.

Comment: Your assumption is equivalent to saying that $|u_0(x)| \leq C\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is the first eigenfuntion. Then $|u(t,x)| \leq Ce^{-\lambda t}\phi(x)$, with $\lambda>0$ the first eigenvalue. For the boudary nehaviour of $\phi$ see for example Lemma 4.6.1, Heat kernels and spectral theory by Davies.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thanks for your answer so much! It has been really helpful for me. Could you explain moreover, why my assumption is equivalent to $|u_0(x)|\leq C\phi(x)$, since here I only assume $|u_0(x)|\leq C{\rm dist}(x,\partial\Omega)$ when $x$ is sufficiently near the boundary.

Comment: Yes, sure. The first eigenfunction is positive in the interior, so any estimate near the boundary extends to a global estimate, enlarging the constant $C$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you so much for your help! May I ask one more question? Lemma 4.6.1 in book Heat kernels and spectral theory requires the domain to be $C^2$ and Lemma 4.6.1 does not hold in non-smooth domain. Do you think in convex polyhedron domain case there still holds: if $|u_0(x)|\leq C_0d(x)$, then $|u(t,x)|\leq Cd(x)$ where constant $C$ independent of $t$?

Comment: This should be true. If $\Omega$ is convex, then $\Delta d$ is concave (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291308/convexity-of-distance-to-boundary-function). If $\Omega$ is also smooth, this implies $\Delta d \leq 0$ and then $d_t-\Delta d \geq 0$. The maximum principle for the heat equation gives $|u(t,x)| \leq Cd(x)$. This estimate does not depend on smoothness if $\Omega$ is convex and should give the result by some approximation, I guess.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thanks for your answer so much! May I ask one more question? Does this conclusion still hold  for domain diffeomorphic to a convex polyhedron (esp, in dim 2 diffeomorphic to a  plane sector)? Or dose this conclustion hold in convex domain for variable coefficient elliptic operator rather than only the laplacian operator $\Delta$?

Comment: For convex sets and a general pure second order operator $L$ the same argument as above applies, since $d$ is concave and then $Ld \leq 0$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thanks for your help so much! Is it still true for an elliptic operator $L$ in divergence form?